# AsyncValidatorFn and AsyncValidator interface - which are the benefits of using one over the other?

Tags: angular, angular-validation

When implementing asynchronous validators in angular - according to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) - I got two options:

- Using [AsyncValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn)
- Using the [AsyncValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) interface

I know HOW to use them but what is the benefit of using one over the other?
Should I favor one or the other?

Comment: I don't get why this is a question? Use `AsyncValidatorFn` if you just want to return validation errors for a control, use `AsyncValidator` if you want to do this and listen for changes. Or always use `AsyncValidator` if you want. It's up to you.

Comment: Doesn't AsyncValidatorFn also listen for changes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant register additional callbacks on the input value changing.

Comment: So if I only need the form control field checked I should use `AsyncValidatorFn` as it would be an overhead if `AsyncValidator` provides additional callbacks which I won't use? Edit: I am just trying to find out if there is a difference in performance.

Comment: Test it for yourself. I'd be surprised if there's any difference in performance - they're only interfaces that have very similar validation signatures.